# Is the emission spectrum of a muonic atom different?

Tags: photons, atomic-physics, spectroscopy

From my quick investigation, the spectrum is based on the [Rydberg formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_formula), 
and with a small change, would lead to

$$
{1 \over \lambda_\mu} = {m_\mu \over m_e} \left( R \left( {1\over n_1^2} - {1\over n_2^2} \right)\right)
$$

where $m_\mu$ is the mass of a muon.

So, taking hydrogen as an example, we would observe similar bands, shifted into the x-ray/gamma range.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost but not quite. Qualitatively the spectrum is the same with the $1/n^2$ spacing, but the scale of the spectrum is set by the *reduced mass* $\mu$, $$\mu = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{m_l}+ \frac{1}{m_p}}$$
where $m_p$ is the proton mass and $m_l$ is the lepton (muon or electron) mass. Since $m_p \approx 2000 m_e$, it is not a large error to take $\mu = m_e$ for an electronic hydrogen atom. But for the muon, $m_\mu \approx 200 m_e \approx 0.1 m_p$, so the error is quite large, around 10%.

Comment: Ok, I'll admit I'm lost here. But rather than have $m_\mu \over m_e$ its just $\mu$ ?

Comment: @jasper Not quite, notice that $\frac{m_\mu}{m_e}$ is dimensionless while $\mu$ has dimensions of mass. So it would be $\frac{\mu_\mu}{\mu_e}$ I suppose (too many $\mu$'s!), and of course $\mu_e\approx m_e$.